# Testable substitute for T4's this.Host as IServiceProvider

Tags: c#, t4

We've created a class to use inside T4 templates that takes `this.Host` as a parameter. It accomplishes by converting `this.Host` into `IServiceProvider` like this...

```
var serviceProvider = this.Host as IServiceProvider;
```

... and then passing `serviceProvider` into the class.

This allows for encapsulation of the code inside T4 templates making them easier to use for more junior developers. The problem comes when we then try to create tests for this class.

`IServiceProvider`, as an interface, is very testable and we can unit test it by creating a substitute for the interface, however the substitute does not have any of the inherent logic that has been derived from `this.Host`.

Testing any of the template functionality through the class when it comes from a test doesn't provide any meaningful benefit. The only meaningful testing done on the class has to be done though manual testing of specific templates. I'd like to change this.

Does anyone know of a good way to pass a meaningful T4 `this.Host` value from a test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this.Host indicates Visual Studio instance you are working on. You can take the active Vs instance by following code

```
        var dte = (EnvDTE80.DTE2)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.14.0"); 
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider = new Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell.ServiceProvider((Microsoft.VisualStudio.OLE.Interop.IServiceProvider)dte.DTE);
```

"VisualStudio.DTE.14.0" refers to a Vs 2015 project on which I' m trying the code if it's working or not.

Note that if there exists more than one Vs instance opened, the code would select one of them randomly. You will need some additional work to be sure to get the right Vs instance.

If you are trying to write unit tests then it' s better to use a Mock framework to isolate your code like Moq. Please check [Moq quick start page](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart).

Comment: Changed this to "VisualStudio.DTE.15.0" for VS 2017 and it works great. We use NSubstitute in our test framework, however we wanted to try and account for more real world scenarios to create a more robust framework.
Cheers for you input !